# makefile doesn't work with -std=c++11 option

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile

I'm trying to play with some C++11 features using g++ 4.8.2 with the following makefile

```
CC=g++
DEBUG=-g
CFLAGS=-c -Wall -std=c++11 $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 $(DEBUG)
SOURCES=test.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=test

all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ -std=c++11
.cpp .o:
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ -std=c++11

clean:
    rm -rf *o $(EXECUTABLE)
```

But when I call "make", here's the error message I get

```
$ make
g++    -c -o test.o test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:18:15: error: range-based ‘for’ loops are not allowed in C++98 mode
  for (int i : {2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 19})
               ^
make: *** [test.o] Error 1
```

It seems to me that -std=c++11 isn't picked up, so I have tried to throw that option in bunch of different places, but still same error occurs.

Current workaround is to use command line directly, and that works for me

```
$ cat test.cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World"  << endl;

    for (int i : {2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17, 19})
    {
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}

$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -W
$ ./test
Hello World
2 3 5 7 9 13 17 19
```

I am just wondering why makefile doesn't do the same thing, and how I could update the makefile to use -std=c++11 option.

Comment: `-std` is being set twice, in CFLAGS and directly in the rule.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various issues with your makefile, but the main one seems to be that your rule for creating objects out of `.cpp` files is wrong. You need something along the lines of

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC)  $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

On the other hand, it might be easier to leverage `make`'s [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html#Catalogue-of-Rules), and set `CXXFLAGS`, `CXX` etc. For example, set

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 $(DEBUG)
CPPFLAGS += .... # pre-processor flags, for include paths etc.
```

and remove the `%.o` rule, letting make do its thing. Note that `CC` and `CFLAGS` are typically used for C code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the space in your `.cpp .o:` rule is confusing make. But I'd go with @juanchopanza's recommendation and switch to the newer pattern syntax - it is much more clear.